# MongoDB watch function not working for asychronous PyMongo

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, watch, tornado-motor

I have a MongoDB documents in a collection that I want to watch. There is an array in each document I want to watch for updates that can I print.

```
pipeline = [
            {"$match": {"id": id}}, # Each document has a unique id field, not to be confused with "_id".
            {"$project": {"log.logs": 1}}
        ]
cursor = main.watch(pipeline)
```

I should note, I'm using Motor with MongoDB because my project is asynchronous. Here is my setup.

```
import motor.motor_asyncio
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from os import getenv

load_dotenv()


MONGO_SERVER_URL = getenv("MONGO_SERVER_URL")
client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(MONGO_SERVER_URL)
db = client["Example-Collection"]
main = db["users"]
```

The `logs` array nested inside the `log` attribute is what I'm trying to watch for updates. As I'm using PyMongo, I've tried both the following approaches.

```
async with cursor as stream:
    while stream.alive:
        change = await stream.try_next()
        
        print(change)

        await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

This one somewhat works, but all I get is the console constantly printing `None`, even when there are changes being done (I double checked with Atlas to see changes were actually being done).

```
async with cursor as stream:
    async for change in stream:
        print(change)

        await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

This is the recommended approach, but it just continues forever doing nothing. It prints nothing to the console and doesn't detect any changes.

Comment: Be careful as `id` is a python built-in. In the pipeline, what are you setting `id` to.

Comment: @BellyBuster My key is not actually "id", it's just what I used for simplicity's sake. In reality it's "ck", standing for central key, and each document in the collection has a unique central key needed for API requests.

Comment: Change streams are only available when mongodb is in replica set mode (as opposed to stand alone mode). Otherwise an error is raised: `OperationFailure: The $changeStream stage is only supported on replica sets`. Are you running mongo in replica set mode?

Your code works for me. Tested on Mongo 6.0 (in rs mode - 3 nodes), motor==3.2.0, pymongo==4.4.1.